# Phpmyadmin Not found in bitnami server before i set ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I have a windows machine but i want to enter via htttps://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin (tunnel putty) but i receive the message Not found The requested URL was not found on this server. My server I set the SSL certificate and I create a domain for my page and also my putty has the config of the tunnel: localhost:443
sourceport: 8888

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. We need more information about the solution you are using to confirm that phpMyAdmin is included  there. You can easily confirm that by running this command in your instance: `curl -LI localhost/phpmyadmin`. If you are using 8888 as source port, you will need to use https://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin to use the SSH tunnel and access the application.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
you need to set putty with the 443 tunnel

Comment: You said in your question: `my putty has the config of the tunnel: localhost:443`... ??